# How to replace all occurrences of target in matched group?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to replace all the quoted strings in a blankets into double
quoted strings in the PostgreSQL.

This is my current scripts and sample input.

```
select regexp_replace(
    'input string',
    '\[(("([^"]+)"|''([^'''']+)'')(, )?)+]',
    '["\3\4"]',
    'g'
)
```

```
["The D'Ascoyne Family: The Duke", 'The Banker', 'The Parson', 'The General', 'The Admiral', 'Young Ascoyne', 'Young Henry', 'Lady Agatha']
['Fabian', '...']
['Peter Griffin', 'Stewie Griffin', 'Brian Griffin', 'Carter Pewterschmidt']
```

However, it replaces only last quoted string and removes everything else.

```
["Lady Agatha"]
["..."]
["Carter Pewterschmidt"]
```

The desired outputs are like the following

```
["The D'Ascoyne Family: The Duke", "The Banker", "The Parson", "The General", "The Admiral", "Young Ascoyne", "Young Henry", "Lady Agatha"]
["Fabian", "..."]
["Peter Griffin", "Stewie Griffin", "Brian Griffin", "Carter Pewterschmidt"]
```

https://regex101.com/r/dvAIBt/1

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Please give further examples of input and expected output. Also it is advisable to put them in the question itself rather than link to them.

Comment: Thanks for viewing my question. I added example of inputs and desired outputs in the question itself.

Comment: Try `REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")|''([^''\\]*(?:\\.[^''\\]*)*)''', '\1"\2"'), '"""', '')` - if there can be three `"`s in your strings, this is not going to help as it assumes there cannot be `"""` in your column.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. @Wiktor 
Looks like this is working out

`REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")|''([^''\\]*(?:\\.[^''\\]*)*)''', '\1"\2"'), '"""', '"')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your strings do not contain `"""` substrings, you can use

```sql
REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")|''([^''\\]*(?:\\.[^''\\]*)*)''', '\1"\2"'), '"""', '"')
```

The `("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")|'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'` regex matches

- `(` - start of Group 1:
- `"` - a `"` char
- `[^"\\]*`  - zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of a `\` followed with any single char and then zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `)` - end of Group 1
- `|` - or
- `'` - a `'` char
- `([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than `'` and `\` and then zero or more sequences of a `\` followed with any single char and then zero or more chars other than `'` and `\`
- `'` - a `'` char.

Since the `"..."` string literals do not need changing, they will be replaced with themselves + `""`, so they will have `"""` on the right, and thus, all you need is to add a `REPLACE` that will replace all `"""`s with `"`s.